# PCS Stonith (fencing) will kill two node cluster if first is down

Tags: cluster, pacemaker, corosync, pcs

I have configured a two node physical server cluster (HP ProLiant DL560 Gen8) using pcs (corosync/pacemaker/pcsd). I have also configured fencing on them using fence_ilo4.

The weird thing will happen if one node goes down (under DOWN i mean power OFF), the second node will die as well. Fencing will kill itself causing both servers to be offline.

How do i correct this behavior?

The thing i tried is to add "`wait_for_all: 0`" and "`expected_votes: 1`" in `/etc/corosync/corosync.conf` under `quorum` section. But it will still kill it.

At some point, some maintenance is to be performed on one of those servers, and it will have to be shutdown. I don't want for the other node to go down if this happens.

Here are some outputs

```
[root@kvm_aquila-02 ~]# pcs quorum status
Quorum information
------------------
Date:             Fri Jun 28 09:07:18 2019
Quorum provider:  corosync_votequorum
Nodes:            2
Node ID:          2
Ring ID:          1/284
Quorate:          Yes

Votequorum information
----------------------
Expected votes:   2
Highest expected: 2
Total votes:      2
Quorum:           1  
Flags:            2Node Quorate 

Membership information
----------------------
    Nodeid      Votes    Qdevice Name
         1          1         NR kvm_aquila-01
         2          1         NR kvm_aquila-02 (local)


[root@kvm_aquila-02 ~]# pcs config show
Cluster Name: kvm_aquila
Corosync Nodes:
 kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02
Pacemaker Nodes:
 kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02

Resources:
 Clone: dlm-clone
  Meta Attrs: interleave=true ordered=true 
  Resource: dlm (class=ocf provider=pacemaker type=controld)
   Operations: monitor interval=30s on-fail=fence (dlm-monitor-interval-30s)
               start interval=0s timeout=90 (dlm-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=100 (dlm-stop-interval-0s)
 Clone: clvmd-clone
  Meta Attrs: interleave=true ordered=true 
  Resource: clvmd (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=clvm)
   Operations: monitor interval=30s on-fail=fence (clvmd-monitor-interval-30s)
               start interval=0s timeout=90s (clvmd-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=90s (clvmd-stop-interval-0s)
 Group: test_VPS
  Resource: test (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=VirtualDomain)
   Attributes: config=/shared/xml/test.xml hypervisor=qemu:///system migration_transport=ssh
   Meta Attrs: allow-migrate=true is-managed=true priority=100 target-role=Started 
   Utilization: cpu=4 hv_memory=4096
   Operations: migrate_from interval=0 timeout=120s (test-migrate_from-interval-0)
               migrate_to interval=0 timeout=120 (test-migrate_to-interval-0)
               monitor interval=10 timeout=30 (test-monitor-interval-10)
               start interval=0s timeout=300s (test-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=300s (test-stop-interval-0s)

Stonith Devices:
 Resource: kvm_aquila-01 (class=stonith type=fence_ilo4)
  Attributes: ipaddr=10.0.4.39 login=fencing passwd=0ToleranciJa pcmk_host_list="kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02"
  Operations: monitor interval=60s (kvm_aquila-01-monitor-interval-60s)
 Resource: kvm_aquila-02 (class=stonith type=fence_ilo4)
  Attributes: ipaddr=10.0.4.49 login=fencing passwd=0ToleranciJa pcmk_host_list="kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02"
  Operations: monitor interval=60s (kvm_aquila-02-monitor-interval-60s)
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
  start dlm-clone then start clvmd-clone (kind:Mandatory)
Colocation Constraints:
  clvmd-clone with dlm-clone (score:INFINITY)
Ticket Constraints:

Alerts:
 No alerts defined

Resources Defaults:
 No defaults set
Operations Defaults:
 No defaults set

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: corosync
 cluster-name: kvm_aquila
 dc-version: 1.1.19-8.el7_6.4-c3c624ea3d
 have-watchdog: false
 last-lrm-refresh: 1561619537
 no-quorum-policy: ignore
 stonith-enabled: true

Quorum:
  Options:
    wait_for_all: 0

[root@kvm_aquila-02 ~]# pcs cluster status
Cluster Status:
 Stack: corosync
 Current DC: kvm_aquila-02 (version 1.1.19-8.el7_6.4-c3c624ea3d) - partition with quorum
 Last updated: Fri Jun 28 09:14:11 2019
 Last change: Thu Jun 27 16:23:44 2019 by root via cibadmin on kvm_aquila-01
 2 nodes configured
 7 resources configured

PCSD Status:
  kvm_aquila-02: Online
  kvm_aquila-01: Online
[root@kvm_aquila-02 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: kvm_aquila
Stack: corosync
Current DC: kvm_aquila-02 (version 1.1.19-8.el7_6.4-c3c624ea3d) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Fri Jun 28 09:14:31 2019
Last change: Thu Jun 27 16:23:44 2019 by root via cibadmin on kvm_aquila-01

2 nodes configured
7 resources configured

Online: [ kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02 ]

Full list of resources:

 kvm_aquila-01  (stonith:fence_ilo4):   Started kvm_aquila-01
 kvm_aquila-02  (stonith:fence_ilo4):   Started kvm_aquila-02
 Clone Set: dlm-clone [dlm]
     Started: [ kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02 ]
 Clone Set: clvmd-clone [clvmd]
     Started: [ kvm_aquila-01 kvm_aquila-02 ]
 Resource Group: test_VPS
     test   (ocf::heartbeat:VirtualDomain): Started kvm_aquila-01

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the STONITH devices configured to be able to fence both nodes. You also do not have location constraints keeping the fence agents responsible for fencing a given node from running on that same node (STONITH suicide), which is a bad practice.

Try configuring the STONITH devices and location constraints like this instead:

```
pcs stonith create kvm_aquila-01 fence_ilo4 pcmk_host_list=kvm_aquila-01 ipaddr=10.0.4.39 login=fencing passwd=0ToleranciJa op monitor interval=60s
pcs stonith create kvm_aquila-02 fence_ilo4 pcmk_host_list=kvm_aquila-02 ipaddr=10.0.4.49 login=fencing passwd=0ToleranciJa op monitor interval=60s
pcs constraint location kvm_aquila-01 avoids kvm_aquila-01=INFINITY
pcs constraint location kvm_aquila-02 avoids kvm_aquila-02=INFINITY
```

Comment: Will try that in a moment, test it immediately and get back with results! Thank you!
In case we need to add a third node (which will hopefully happen soon as it is definitely planned). do i need to remove constraints or just add the third constraint for third node? Or in that case i just remove constraints and add all three nodes to "pcmk_host_list" ?. BTW, i Just realized something. Anytime i cut the power to node2, the node1 dies, that is commints suicide. But if i cut the power to node1, then node2 continues to run just fine. Weird or to be expected under this setup that i currently have?

Comment: @MarkoTodoric When you add the third node, you'll have to add a third fencing device and a third constraint. In regards to `aquila-01` getting fenced when `aquila-02` has it's power cut, that's not expected behavior. Let's see if that changes once you've corrected the fencing configuration.

Comment: Works like a charm when I've set just constraints! :) Thanks a lot ! Node is not committing suicide anymore. :)